# Android. Программное копирование разметки на основе готового макета xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Задача такая: выводить краткую информацию о статьях в виде таблиц. Соответственно сколько статей в категории, столько  и должно быть создано и выведено таблиц. Хотелось бы не просто программно создавать разметку, а опираться на один и тот же готовый xml-макет таблицы и просто заполнять его разными данными в цикле. Подскажите, возможно ли это и как реализовать?

Comment: RecyclerView погуглите. Даже циклов не надо)

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю заранее количество статей, они приходят в приложение с удалённого сервера и формировать разметку нужно динамически каждый раз

Comment: RecyclerView как раз и не требует знания размера списка. У Ханнесдорфмана есть шикарная [библиотека](https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates) для случая, когда в одном списке могут оказаться совершенно разные элементы

Comment: Задача решена с помощью RecyclerView, спасибо за наводку!